# Как самостоятельно преобразовывать текст в речь?

Tags: python, c++

Проблема такая, что у меня есть проект по созданию голосового помощника. Хочу присобачить к нему голос не из интернета, а свой. Возник вопрос, как это сделать? Можете посоветовать литературу по этой теме? Пишу на Python/C++

Answer (score 1):

Ключевое слово для Вас - TTS (Text To Speach). Собственно, открываем гугли ищем. И тут же находим https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-text-speech-python/

устанавливаем пакет `pip install gTTS`

Тестируем

```
# Импортируем нужный модуль 
# для преобразования
from gtts import gTTS
  
# Если есть модуль, можно играть сконвертированное аудио
import os
  
# Текст, который нужно преобразовать/произнести
mytext = 'Welcome to geeksforgeeks!'
  
# Указываем нужный язык
language = 'en'
  
# Передаем текст и язык в движок TTS
# добавляя slow=False, что говорит 
# что модуль должен сконвертировать аудио
# с высокой скоростью
myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
  
# сохраним результат в mp3
myobj.save("welcome.mp3")
  
# воспроизведем плеером
os.system("mpg321 welcome.mp3")
```

но если хочется совсем свой, то тут все немного сложнее

Comment: в том то и дело, что я хочу прям совсем свой голос. Проблема в вопросе была именно в этом

Comment: а у Вас есть несколько десятков лет, лингвистическое/филологическое образование и запас еды? В целом, если для английского, то можно взять произношение всех слов (примеры тут https://easypronunciation.com/en/russian-letters-pronunciation-ipa-chart, к сожалению, для русского я не видел большой таблицы) и взять произношение всех звуков (тут есть хороший набор https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Russian) и попробовать слепить. Либо просто взять и наговорить.

Comment: вот пример таких словарей для многих языков https://github.com/open-dict-data/ipa-dict . Понятно, что всегда есть хитрые слова, которые и человек не всегда сходу прочитает правильно (например, в английcком read читается по разному, в зависимости от того, в каком оно времени или live, но тут проще). Но я пока нигде не видел таких словарей для русского или украинского. Где то читал, что более красиво получается все сделать, если записывать произношение слогов, а не отдельных звуков.